# Patroni switchover. How to choose target server in API-request?

Tags: postgresql, patroni

Simple question. We have Postgres cluster with 3 servers, for example:

```
- serverA_1
- serverA_2
- serverB.
```

Server A-2 cant't be leader without manual switch.
For example right now leader is **serverA-1**. I want't to switchover leader in **serverB**. What API request I should send?

```
curl -s http://serverA_1:8008/switchover -XPOST -d '{"leader":"serverA_1"}'
```

or

```
curl -s http://serverB:8008/switchover -XPOST -d '{"leader":"serverB"}'
```

Logic said me that **second** request, bit in our current jenkins job used **first** (as if we say current leader, that you are not leader now).

Comment: this one: curl -s http://serverB:8008/switchover -XPOST -d '{"leader":"serverB"}'

Answer (score 0):

Example: perform a failover to the specific node:

$ **curl -s http://localhost:8009/failover -XPOST -d '{"candidate":"postgresql1"}'**

Successfully failed over to "postgresql1"

Example: schedule a switchover from the leader to any other healthy replica in the cluster at a specific time:

$ **curl -s http://localhost:8008/switchover -XPOST -d 

'{"leader":"postgresql0","scheduled_at":"2019-09-24T12:00+00"}'**

Switchover scheduled

Answer (score 0):

This one is work for switchover with patroni in maintance enable mode:

```
curl -s http://server_A1:8008/switchover -XPOST -d '{"leader":"server_A1", "candidate":"serverB"}'
```